# Winform SaveFileDialog usage through a php script

Tags: c#, php, winforms, savefiledialog

I'm in the process of trying to link to a php script hosted on a separate server can allow me to browse the files I already have on my server.

I didn't write this script and was provided to me by a friend who said it would simply return a string of all the files and folders currently held on the server. My task is to implement it via this C# Winform application.

My question is this: is there a way I can create a similar file upload system, with the same functionality as the in built SaveFileDialog? Or is this already built in?

I ask because I don't think it would be very good, or user friendly, to simply have people read a bunch lines of text, would be nice is they could use something they are more familiar with I think.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in the `SaveFileDialog` so a custom control would need to be created to facilitate the behavior you're after.

You'll find solutions that sound possible like [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy) but these are largely UI enhancements and do no offer the extensible FileSystem-like layer you would need to achieve what you're after.